# Pyspark aggregation using groupBy is very slow compared to Scala

Tags: python, scala, apache-spark, pyspark

I ported a Scala code that does simple aggregation into Python:

```
from time import time
from utils import notHeader, parse, pprint
from pyspark import SparkContext

start = time()
src = "linkage"
sc = SparkContext("spark://aiur.local:7077", "linkage - Python")
rawRdd = sc.textFile(src)
noheader = rawRdd.filter(notHeader)
parsed = noheader.map(parse)
grouped = parsed.groupBy(lambda md: md.matched)
res = grouped.mapValues(lambda vals: len(vals)).collect()
for x in res: pprint(x)
diff = time() - start
mins, secs = diff / 60, diff % 60
print "Analysis took {} mins and {} secs".format(int(mins), int(secs))
sc.stop()
```

utils.py:

```
from collections import namedtuple

def isHeader(line):
    return line.find("id_1") >= 0

def notHeader(line):
    return not isHeader(line)

def pprint(s):
    print s

MatchedData = namedtuple("MatchedData", "id_1 id_2 scores matched")

def parse(line):
    pieces = line.split(",")
    return MatchedData(pieces[0], pieces[1], pieces[2:11], pieces[11])
```

And the Scala version:

```
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext
import org.apache.spark.SparkConf

object SparkTest {
    def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
        val start: Long = System.currentTimeMillis/1000
        val filePath = "linkage"
        val conf = new SparkConf()
            .setAppName("linkage - Scala")
            .setMaster("spark://aiur.local:7077")
        val sc = new SparkContext(conf)
        val rawblocks = sc.textFile(filePath)
        val noheader = rawblocks.filter(x => !isHeader(x))
        val parsed = noheader.map(line => parse(line))
        val grouped = parsed.groupBy(md => md.matched)
        grouped.mapValues(x => x.size).collect().foreach(println)
        val diff = System.currentTimeMillis/1000 - start
        val (mins, secs) = (diff / 60, diff % 60)
        val pf = printf("Analysis took %d mins and %d secs", mins, secs)
        println(pf)
        sc.stop()
    }

    def isHeader(line: String): Boolean = {
        line.contains("id_1")
    }

    def toDouble(s: String): Double = {
        if ("?".equals(s)) Double.NaN else s.toDouble
    }

    case class MatchData(id1: Int, id2: Int,
        scores: Array[Double], matched: Boolean)

    def parse(line: String) = {
        val pieces = line.split(",")
        val id1 = pieces(0).toInt
        val id2 = pieces(1).toInt
        val scores = pieces.slice(2, 11).map(toDouble)
        val matched = pieces(11).toBoolean
        MatchData(id1, id2, scores, matched)
    }
}
```

The Scala version completes in 26 secs but the Python version took ~6 mins. The logs shows a very big difference in the completion of the respective collect() calls.

Python:

```
17/01/25 16:22:10 INFO DAGScheduler: ResultStage 1 (collect at /Users/esamson/Hackspace/Spark/run_py/dcg.py:12) finished in 234.860 s
17/01/25 16:22:10 INFO DAGScheduler: Job 0 finished: collect at /Users/esamson/Hackspace/Spark/run_py/dcg.py:12, took 346.675760 s
```

Scala:

```
17/01/25 16:26:23 INFO DAGScheduler: ResultStage 1 (collect at Spark.scala:17) finished in 9.619 s
17/01/25 16:26:23 INFO DAGScheduler: Job 0 finished: collect at Spark.scala:17, took 22.022075 s
```

'groupBy' seems to be the only call of significance. So, is there a way I can improve the performance on the Python code?

Comment: Any reasons not to use the dataframe API and the CSV read format? Performance will likely improve to the scala level if not better.

Comment: @maasg Would definitely try that

Answer (score 1):

You are using RDDs and therefore when you do transformations on them (e.g. groupby, map) you have to pass functions to them. When you pass these functions in scala then the functions are simply run. When you do the same in python, spark needs to serialize these functions, open a python VM on each executor and then when the function needs to run it needs to convert the scala data to python, pass it to the python VM and then pass and convert the results.

All these conversions take a lot of work and therefore RDD work in pyspark is generally much slower than scala.

A possible way to go around this is to use dataframe logic which allow the use of functions already created (in pyspark.sql.functions) which behind the scenes use scala functions. This would look something like this (for spark 2.0):

```
from pyspark import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.functions import size

src = "linkage"
spark = SparkSession.builder.master(""spark://aiur.local:7077"").appName(""linkage - Python"").getOrCreate()
df = spark.read.option("header", "true").csv(src)
res = df.groupby("md").agg(size(df.vals)).collect()
...
```

This of course assumes matched and vals are the column names.